# JDBC Oracle Result set Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, sql, oracle, exception, jdbc

I have a multi threaded program which connects to a oracle database.

The first thread executes a "big" query and loads the objects in to a LinkedBlockingQueue. There are around 200,000 objects.

The second thread polls this list, and for each object, it runs 14 other queries, updating the object parameters. Then I connect to another database, one final time, get corresponding object for this current object, create a hybrid object containing these two objects and sends it to third thread.

I am using a single statement and multiple result sets for each one of these 14 queries.

```
    stat=predefinedobject.getConnection().createStatement();  
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ResultSet rs1 = null;
    ResultSet rs2 = null;
    ResultSet rs3 = null;
          .
          .
    rs=stat.executeQuery(Query1);
    while(rs.next()) {
        object1.setParameter1(rs.getString(5));
    }
    SqlUtils.closeResultSet(rs);

    rs1=stat.executeQuery(Query2);
    while(rs1.next()) {
        object1.setParameter2(rs1.getString(5));
    }
    SqlUtils.closeResultSet(rs1);
           .
           .
           .
    SqlUtils.closeResultSet(rs14);
    SqlUtils.closeResultSet(stat);
```

I am getting the null pointer exception after some time.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.getNumRows(T4C8Oall.java:876)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:825)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1049)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CStatement.java:845)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1154)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1313)
```

Comment: What Oracle server and driver version?

Comment: I think we are using Oracle 11g, no idea about the driver version though

Comment: The error seems to occur inside the driver, which could indicate a bug in the driver; or maybe your `SqlUtils.closeResultSet` ignores exceptions that might be relevant leading to an inconsistent state inside the driver (which would still be a bug in the driver). I suggest you 1) check the driver version and upgrade to the latest, 2) check if your utility method ignores exceptions and see if any are occurring there.

Comment: This error could also be due to a sintax error in the query

Answer (score 3):

Double check your sql query strings , 
it seems you concatenate the query but missing some space in it.

For example;

```
String sql="select"+MYCOULUM+" form MYTABLE"
```

will produce the following string

```
selectMYCOULUM form MYTABLE
```

and executing such query will result this error for oracle jdbc driver

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I've used upper case `CALL` instead of lower case `call` to call stored proc.

For example, `{ ?= CALL proc_name(?) }` is giving the same error. Once I change to `{ ?= call proc_name(?) }` it is working

Comment: me too, I changed `CALL` to `call` and the exception gone.

Comment: I also have an out `SYS_REFCURSOR` as first parameter and the `query` should be
`{call MY_SP_NAME(?, :param1, :param2)}` . first parameter `?` is that ref cursor

Answer (score 0):

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) says - By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an open one exists.

So may be try to create a new Statement object each time you want to query the database

Comment: Still I am getting the same Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.getNumRows(T4C8Oall.java:876)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:825)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1049)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CStatement.java:845)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1154)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1313)`

Comment: As the error seems to occur inside the driver, I'd sooner attribute it to a bug in the driver.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel a similar issue is over [here](http://dbaspot.com/oracle-server/129809-jdbc-execute-statement-brackets-nullpointerexception.html) may be some i guess it is some query problem

Comment: @SparkOn That still describes a bug in the driver; a JDBC driver should only ever throw `SQLException`, all others should be considered a driver bug. But agreed: having the actual queries used that cause the exception might be helpful in finding a workaround.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel `JDBC driver should only ever throw SQLException` completely agreed